# Not able to understand the way the debconf variables are initialized in the preseed configuration

Tags: debian, ubuntu, pxe, preseed, debconf

Recently I inherited a lab but unfortunately the person who had setup has left the organization. I am finding trouble in understanding the pxe installation flow at the point where the debconf variables are initialized in the preseed configuration.

part of preseed configuration:

```
### Account setup
d-i passwd/user-fullname string TEST User
d-i passwd/username string test
d-i passwd/user-password-crypted password xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
d-i user-setup/allow-password-weak boolean true
d-i user-setup/encrypt-home boolean false

### Boot loader installation
d-i grub-installer/only_debian boolean true
d-i grub-installer/with_other_os boolean true

### Finishing up the installation
d-i finish-install/reboot_in_progress note

### Custom stuff, update pre-late.sh if creating new variables
base-config      test/http/server       string 
base-config      test/ubuntu/release    string 16.04 
base-config      test/nfs/server        string 10.44.55.5
base-config      test/nfs/config        string /export/vol01/ubuntu/config
base-config      test/nis/domain        string ccd
base-config      test/nis/server        string 10.44.55.100 10.44.55.101

#### Advanced options
d-i preseed/late_command   string wget http://10.44.55.5/ubuntu/config/pre-late.sh -O /tmp/pre-late.sh; sh -x /tmp/pre-late.sh
d-i     preseed/run     string classes.sh
```

The above mentioned debconf variables test/ubuntu/release, test/nfs/server, test/nfs/config, test/nfs/domain and test/nis/server are being extracted and set the environment variables as shown below in the pre_late-sh script that is executed with preseed/late_command in the above preseed configuration.

```
#!/bin/sh

#Source debconf library
. /usr/share/debconf/confmodule

db_get test/ubuntu/release
export RELEASE="$RET"
db_get test/nfs/server
export NFS_SERVER="$RET"
db_get test/nfs/config
export NFS_CONFIG="$RET"
db_get test/nis/domain
export NIS_DOMAIN="$RET"
db_get test/nis/server
export NIS_SERVER="$RET"
```

I tried to google a lot about the way of initializing the debconf variables but not able to understand the way they are getting initialized here using base-config. Can someone help me to understand how is this being done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preseeding stores the defined variables in the appropriate `debconf` database; the installer’s for `d-i`-owned variables, the system’s (in `/var/cache/debconf`) for others. So all the `base-config` variables end up stored in the system `debconf` database.

`db_get`, which is provided by `/usr/share/debconf/confmodule`, retrieves the value of the named variable from the `debconf` database, and stores it in the `RET` variable. So

```
db_get test/ubuntu/release
export RELEASE="$RET"
```

retrieves the value of `test/ubuntu/release`, and stores it in the environment variable `RELEASE`.

See [the preseeding page on the Debian wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianInstaller/Preseed) for details of preseeding, and [the `debconf` page on the Debian wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/debconf) for details of `debconf`.

Comment: @ Stephen - Thanks for your explanation. So, is there no specific format to the base-config variable defined? Is the name "test/nfs/server" just a simple text? Will it work even if I change "test/nfs/server" to "nfs/server" by removing the word test?

Comment: `base-config` is a [historical remnant](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianInstaller/RemoveBaseConfig). You can remove `test/`; but you should have a unique prefix on your variables, to avoid conflicts in future. Since this is specific to your organisation, your organisation’s name would make a suitable prefix IMO.

Comment: @ Stephen - Thank you very much for your answer. Now it is clear.